# Basic Paper Rock Scissors player pick returns undefined

Tags: javascript

Basically the player Choice returns undefined. When I pass console.log('rock') I can see it in the console, although the 'return' value is not being shown in the console

```
function playerChoice(){
    paperButton.addEventListener('click', function (){
        return 'paper'
    }) 
    rockButton.addEventListener('click', function (){
        return 'rock'
    }) 
    scissorsButton.addEventListener('click', function (){
        return 'scissors'

    }) 
}
```

Comment: Your code does not make any sense. What exactly do you want to achieve with the function here?

Comment: Time you learn about asynchronous programming. All that return statement is doing is returning that string to the event handler. It has NOTHING to do with the playerChoice function.

Comment: Basically I need the value paper rock or scissors after clicking on the button which I pass to another function

Comment: Yes and you need to rethink your logic. You should just be calling a method with what was picked. `userPicked("rock")` Other option is to use promises, but seems like overkill for a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is asynchronous JavaScript code, so you can't write it this way. Instead you *must* provide some mechanism for forwarding the result if/when it does occur. this is easily done with a callback function:

```
function playerChoice(cb) {
    paperButton.addEventListener('click', function (){
        cb('paper');
    }) 
    rockButton.addEventListener('click', function (){
        cb('rock');
    }) 
    scissorsButton.addEventListener('click', function (){
        cb('scissors');
    })
}
```

Where you'd call it like this:

```
playerChoice(function(choice) {
  console.log("You picked " + choice);
});
```

Remember that `function()` you supply to the `click` handler **runs in the distant, unforeseen future** as far as the computer is concerned. Additionally, you cannot return anything meaningful from a callback function, the value is ignored.

In other words, the computer does not sit around waiting for you to click a button so it can return that value. Instead it sets up an *event listener* that will engage if/when that action occurs. It's your job to tell JavaScript what you want to do at that point in time. Your main function has long since terminated and returned whatever it was going to return, so you have no control over that.

This means you usually set up some kind of mechanism for propagating the result of that operation. A callback function is common, but you could also do whatever you want there, run some other code, populate a form value, it's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding what your function does. addEventListener does exactly just that. It attaches an event listener to those buttons for a click event and runs that callback function when the event is run. It does not run the function playerChoice().

```
function playerChoice(choice) {
    // choice is a string, do whatever you want with it
    // you can return choice here which looks like what you wanted to do originally
}

paperButton.addEventListener('click', function (){
        playerChoice('paper');
    }); 
rockButton.addEventListener('click', function (){
        playerChoice('rock');
    }); 
scissorsButton.addEventListener('click', function (){
        playerChoice('scissors');
    });
```